# Sequence question problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $a_n=\sqrt[3]{n^3+c}-n$ where $c > 0,$ it's a real const.
Show that $0<a_n<\frac{c}{3n^2}$ is true, for all $n$ that belong to Natural Numbers. Hint: $(n+a_n)^3=n^3+c$.

Comment: $a_n$? Where does that come from? I think you have a typo somewhere...

Comment: It’s a notation.

Comment: Oh wait, ok, I somehow missed it on the left side. Clear now...

Comment: Ok . Im stuck in this one..

Comment: Try to arrive where Karn Watcharasupat was hinting you. -  But first: Can you arrive at the equation given in the hint you posted in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- If $a>b>0,$ then $$\sqrt[3]a>\sqrt[3]b$$
- $(n+a_n)^3=n^3+3n^2a_n+3na_n^2+a_n^3=n^3+c$ thus $$a_n(3n^2+3na_n+a_n^2)=c$$
- If $x,y,k>0$, then $$\frac{x}{y}>\frac{x}{y+k}$$

Comment: This answer is actually good. I am pretty reluctant to elaborate more...